# Why is my terminal rejecting my sudo command as permission denied

Tags: permissions, sudo

```
sudo gresource extract gtk.gresource \
 /usr/share/themes/MyCustomTheme19929/gtk-3.0/gtkgresource \
 >/usr/share/themes/MyCustomTheme19929/gtk-3.0/what.css 
bash: /usr/share/themes/MyCustomTheme19929/gtk-3.0/what.css: 
Permission denied
```

Comment: Can you please include what Linux distro you are using?

Comment: This would be Ubuntu 22.04 I guess. Whatever was the current as of 7 days ago. I haven't found where I can right click a certain window like My Computer in Windows to review the exact OS version.